# Find intersection point of chord and radius (or diameter)

Tags: circles

A,B,C,D coordinates are known, how can I calculate E coordinates?

[graphic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TD8qm.jpg)

Thanks

Comment: Find equations of the two lines, solve them algebraically to obtain the intersection point E.

Comment: thanks for your anwser, I'm pretty noob about Math and geometry.. I'm trying to build a mini game and I need to write some algo to find that intersection. I have no idea what "Find equations of the two lines" and "solve them algebraically" means..

Comment: I do not believe that you know what "circle" and "chord" and "radius" are but do not understand what "equations" and "algebra" mean. There are plenty of examples to be found, and the special case where A is (0, 0) should simplify the general case.

Comment: I just learned what chord means cause I've already search a lot about my problem but I can't find that specific case and I'm not able to expand or deduct from another case.. I believe I got to deal with angles but I don't know where to go

Comment: Here is [one example](http://thirdpartyninjas.com/blog/2008/10/07/line-segment-intersection/) although there is a typo in the last equation where $U_{a}$ should be $U_{b}$.

Comment: Another
[reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2136906/122782)
has a general formula 
for intersection of the two lines through points z1,z2 and z3,z4.

Comment: thank you guys, but I think solving this is too high level for me..

Comment: @LePioo if this is too high level, then MSE is probably wrong website to get an answer.

Comment: Sorry about that, I thought the answer would be more simple to understand, should I close or delete it?

Comment: I've made a simplification of my problem here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2424445/find-3rd-point-of-triangle-with-the-opposite-angle