# Find 3rd point of triangle with the opposite angle

Tags: triangles

I got a triangle, I know A and B coordinates, I know all angles, how can I calculate C coordinates?

[Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cw1xC.jpg)

Comment: You cannot. The locus of constant $\angle BCA$ are two circular arcs with end points $A,B$. You need more info to fix the location of $C$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can.  If you put A at $(-1,0)$ and B at $(0,1)$, then any point $C$ on the unit circle will make a right triangle with A and B.  Which means the coordinates of A and B and the measure of the angle C are not enough.  If you know one more side length or one more angle, you can use the law of sines to get the other measurements.

Comment: thanks for your answer I'll look into that

Comment: I've found the others angles and edited my question, how can I use the law of sines in that case ?

Comment: @LePioo: With the law of sines you can get the other side lengths.  That should be enough to find the coordinates of the third point.